# Inserting Rows that don't exist and use previous value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to insert rows that do not exist in the table that I am pulling from, it is sequenced by the days_to_cancel column and starts back at zero with a new Year/Month entry. I am using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE reporting.tbl_exec_retention_curve_cumulative (days_to_cancel int, cancels int, cumulative_cancels int, enroll_dt varchar(50));
SELECT rc.days_to_cancel,
       rc.cancels,
       (@run_total := CASE WHEN rc.days_to_cancel <> 0 THEN @run_total + 
       rc.cancels ELSE rc.cancels END) AS cumulative_cancels,
       LEFT(rc.client_enroll_dt,7) AS client_enroll_dt
FROM   (SELECT rc.days_to_cancel,
               SUM(CASE WHEN rc.client_status = 'CAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancels,
               LEFT(rc.client_enroll_dt,7) AS client_enroll_dt
        FROM   t1.table rc
        GROUP BY 1,3
        ORDER BY 3,1
        ) rc
JOIN    (SELECT @run_total := 0) r
GROUP BY 1,4
ORDER BY 4,1;
```

I get a sample result of the following

```
days_to_cancel | cancels | cumulative_cancels | client_enroll_dt
---------------+---------+--------------------+------------------
       42      |    2    |         376        |     2019-02
       47      |    0    |         376        |     2019-02
       0       |    0    |         0          |     2019-03
       10      |    4    |         4          |     2019-03
       11      |    9    |         13         |     2019-03
```

So my goal is to input the missing days and use the previous cumulative_cancels and enroll_dt values and 0 for the cancels column when I input that new row for those missing days. I've tried multiple ways including using variables, but I'm at a loss of what to do. I don't know if it's possible considering the rows never existed in the first place. If it matters I am on version 10.0.35 of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I just imagine that you fetched data from `t1.table` and want to insert your result into the same table.

My solution is putting your result into a temporary table then find the missing days by left join.

```sql
SELECT rc.days_to_cancel,
       rc.cancels,
       (@run_total := CASE WHEN rc.days_to_cancel <> 0 THEN @run_total + 
       rc.cancels ELSE rc.cancels END) AS cumulative_cancels,
       LEFT(rc.client_enroll_dt,7) AS client_enroll_dt
--put your result into a temp table
into #temp
FROM   (SELECT rc.days_to_cancel,
               SUM(CASE WHEN rc.client_status = 'CAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancels,
               LEFT(rc.client_enroll_dt,7) AS client_enroll_dt
        FROM   t1.table rc
        GROUP BY 1,3
        ORDER BY 3,1
        ) rc
JOIN    (SELECT @run_total := 0) r
GROUP BY 1,4
ORDER BY 4,1;


insert into t1.table (days_to_cancel, cancels,cumulative_cancels, client_enroll_dt)
select tm.days_to_cancel, tm.cancels, tm.cumulative_cancels, tm.client_enroll_d from #temp tm
left join t1.table rc on rc.days_to_cancel = tm.days_to_cancel
where rc.days_to_cancel is null --find out missing days

drop table #temp
```